# Kafka Streams - Pause and resume

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a streams application that consumes messages usually fast but sometimes takes a lot of time (up to 30 min). The behavior is in-deterministic and we do not know before processing the message. We deploy our application in Kubernetes where pods going down and scaling up is normal. When all pods are stuck in processing messages for a long time, any new pods scale up or going down kick off rebalancing which takes a lot of time, and sometimes never completes due to the poll thread blocked.

I am trying to pause and resume Kafka streams which theoretically should not block poll so it should not block rebalancing. What is the ideal programming model to achieve the following? I know this is fairly easy to accomplish when using Kafka consumer model (not streams)

- Start processing a message
- Spawn a new thread to process message
- Pause kafka streams which unblocks poll and do not consume any new messages
- When finished processing message

  - Forward message to sink (output topic)
  - commit offset and resume streams

I have tried the following. It has multiple problems:

- When kafka streams is paused, forward is hanged forever
- If I resume streams and then forward, it is not hanged but no message in output topic

'''
public class Test1 {

```
static KafkaStreams streams;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Set up the configuration properties
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-streams-app");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 180000)

    Topology builder = new Topology();

    // Add a source processor node
    builder.addSource("Source", "input");

    // Add a processor node
    builder.addProcessor("Processor", MyProcessor::new, "Source");

  
    builder.addSink("sendto", "output", Serdes.String().serializer(), Serdes.String().serializer(),"Processor");

    // Build the topology
    streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, config);

    // Start the KafkaStreams instance
    streams.start();

    // Add shutdown hook to gracefully close the KafkaStreams instance
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
}

static class MyProcessor implements Processor<String, String, String, String> {
    private ProcessorContext context;
    private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }


    @Override
    public void process(Record<String, String> record) {
        System.out.println("In processing");

        streams.pause();
        executorService.schedule(() -> {
            System.out.println("Started processing..sleeping");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println("OUT processing...");

            context.forward(new Record<>("test1", "value",1l), "sendto");
            context.commit();
            streams.resume();

        }, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Streams is not flexible enough. If it has a single message at hand and processing it takes a long time, it won't call `poll()`.

You might need to fall back to using a `KafkaConsumer` instead so you have more control over it. Or you try to increase `max.poll.timeout.ms` accordingly, but I would actually not recommend it -- 30 minutes would be a really high value and might cause other issues.

Using `ScheduledExecutorService` is a very bad idea anyway and might break your application. Kafka Streams does not allow to run your own background threads.